# can't use the ansible extra vars values in playbook task

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

When running the ansible playbook, i am providing the extra vars especially for **modules** variable where i am passing multiple values.

```
ansible-playbook abc.yml  --extra-vars "status=enable modules='redis apache zookeeper'"
```

I want to run the below task when the modules in extra vars has "redis"

```
  - name: fetch ports
    shell: ll | grep -i "ports"
    when:  modules == "redis"
```

However, the above task is getting skipped even when the module  in extra vars has "redis". Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `modules` variable you supplied is a string, you have 2 options:

1. try to search for "redis" in the supplied string, not the ideal option because it would validate to true if you had supplied string like `redisv2 apache zookeeper`.
2. split the string to a list using the space as a delimiter, and then validate to true if the "redis" is in one of the list elements.

for the 2nd option, here is how to do it:

```
  - name: fetch ports
    shell: ll | grep -i "ports"
    when: '"redis" in modules.split(" ")'
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.